# При нажатии на FloatingActionButton чтобы появлялись две кнопки

Tags: android

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на `FloatingActionButton` появлялись две другие круглые кнопки, чтобы нажав на них можно было открыть `Activity`? Желательно стандартными средствами

типа как тут

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В настоящее время нет готового решения из коробки.
Единственный способ сделать это быстро и легко - это использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Могу посоветовать библиотеку [FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial](https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial)

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть